# Bug in star rating under product title

Tags: rating, review

I'm seeing this star rating problem on my site:
https://goldenshop.be/product/golds-gym-strength-stringer-goud/

As you can see, the first star seems to have a duplicated half star in the background. How can I remove this bug?

Thanks in advance for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this in css codes :

```
    .woocommerce .star-rating span {
     text-indent: 999px;
     left: 0px;  <----- 2px to 0px
     }
     .woocommerce .star-rating span::before 
     {
     text-indent: 0px; <----- -2px to 0px;
     }
```